# finding sub-segment of list of words in any order using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, special-characters, unordered

I have a list of words and i have to find the minimum word sub-segment of words, neglecting any special characters and digits,
this sub-segment can have words in any order and case-insensitive search
and this coding is to be done in java

for e.g.

```
aaaa aaaa cccc cccc bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb Bbbb Aaaa Cccc
```

and have words

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

then it should give me output as

```
Bbbb Aaaa Cccc
```

i am aware about regular expression (regex in java) but, new to it so any help would be of great use..

Comment: Can strings like `aaa aAa aaA AAA` occur in the searched string? (Different variations of same "word" following each other.) Is the number of words fixed?

Comment: yes search is case in sensitive and i need to find the sequence of words in any order from the string which will be sub-segment of the string.. but every words is included at once in sub-segment.. no of words are not fixed... but it surely less than no of words in the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is to construct a regex like this:

```
(?i)\b(aaaa|bbbb|cccc)(?=\W+(\w+)\W+(\w+)\b)
\__/  \_____________/    \______/         \__ makes sure it's a complete word
 |           |               \____ repeat N-1 times (N = number of words)
 |           \___ all words alternated to match the first word
 \__ case insensitive matching
```

Then with Java check that the capturing groups contain all the words. If they do you found a match, if not, search for next match and repeat.

---

You could take this all the way to be solved with regex only, but you have to construct the proper expression:

```
(?i)\b(words)\W+(?!\1\b)(words)\W+(?!(?:\1|\2)\b)(words)\b
       \___/ \________________/   \_____________/
         |           |                  |
  list of all the    |         lookahead has to include
  words alternated   |         all previous capturing groups
                     |
             repeat N-1 times but you have to 
             change the lookahead each time
```

This would be a pretty big expression for many words, altho `words` can be any expression that matches all allowed words (doesn't have to be alternations).